# Scrape HTML content of a page once value of an <option> tag is selected

Tags: html, xml, r, sharepoint

I need the html of page once we select the value of options.

```
url="http://ceogoa.nic.in/appln/UIL/ElectoralRoll.aspx"
url=html(url)
text=url%>%html_nodes(xpath='//*@id="ctl00_Main_drpAC"]/option')%>%html_text() 
values=url%>%html_nodes(xpath='//*@id="ctl00_Main_drpAC"]/option')%>%html_attr("value")
```

This code gives the values of available options. Now I want to access the page for each value. I tried to modify url using query strings. But it didn't work out.

Comment: It just calls `http://ceogoa.nic.in/appln/UIL/ElectoralRoll.aspx` with a different `ctl00$Main$drpAC` parameter for each field. Use Developer Tools on any decent/modern browser, lookup the XHR requests, copy the form data and make `httr:GET` or `rvest::html` (etc) requests on those URLs. The site uses SharePoint as a back end, so the form data and variable names are needlessly ugly, but that's Microsoft technologies for you.

Comment: If you don't want to go that route, you'll need to use selenium with that site since it uses JavaScript actions once an `<option>` on the `<select>` component is chosen.

Comment: If I use your second approach, I'll get the page only for one tag value at a time. There are forty tag values. I am trying to grasp your first suggestion.

Comment: you're going to have to access it page-by-page regardless of the method. it will either be a scripted submit via selenium or figuring out the appropriate query strings (made _really_ difficult since it's SharePoint) and doing individual `httr` or `rvest` calls.

Comment: I found out query string.. they are weird. .. (1)ctl00$ToolkitScriptManager=ctl00$ToolkitScriptManager|ctl00$Main$btnSearch (2)_TSM_HiddenField_=w7jpIJ8LMgM7u8gLjQBxxbgFlVTP1p_vIL8EuJVw1w1 (3)__EVENTTARGET (4)__EVENTARGUMENT (6)ctl00$Main$drpAC=05001 (7)ctl00$Main$vcAC_ClientState (8)__ASYNCPOST=true (9)ctl00$Main$btnSearch=Search.. But it doesn't work out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it does (work out)…

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(pbapply)

# Get the constituencies --------------------------------------------------

URL <- "http://ceogoa.nic.in/appln/UIL/ElectoralRoll.aspx"
electoral <- read_html(URL)
constituency <- grep("^0$", html_attr(html_nodes(electoral, "option"), "value"), value=TRUE, invert=TRUE)

# Found this and the other wretched SharePoint parameters via
# Developer Tools in Chrome

view_state <- "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"

get_parts <- function(cons) {

  POST("http://ceogoa.nic.in/appln/UIL/ElectoralRoll.aspx", 
       body=list(
         `ctl00$Main$drpAC`=cons, # <------ here's where we use the parameter
         `ctl00$ToolkitScriptManager`="ctl00$ToolkitScriptManager|ctl00$Main$btnSearch",
         `_TSM_HiddenField_`="gw7jpIJ8LMgM7u8gLjQBxxbgFlVTP1p_vIL8EuJVw1w1",
         `ctl00$Main$vcAC_ClientState`=NULL,
         `__ASYNCPOST`=TRUE,
         `__EVENTTARGET`=NULL,
         `__EVENTARGUMENT`=NULL,
         `__VIEWSTATE`=view_state,
         `ctl00$Main$btnSearch`="Search"),
       encode="form") -> res

  doc <- read_html(content(res, as="text"))
  tab <- html_table(html_nodes(doc, "table.mGrid")[[1]], fill=TRUE)
  tab$constituency <- cons
  tab

}

dat <- pblapply(constituency, get_parts)
```

NOTE that you'll need to do more cleanup of the tables than I did if you want to make a giant data frame out of them (if you want the tables). If you want the PDF links that should be easy to do but pls don't tag on either cleanup or alternate extraction questions to this one.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. What is URL in for code?              url="http://ceogoa.nic.in/appln/UIL/ElectoralRoll.aspx"

Comment: apologies for missing that in my hasty copy. i added it to the answer.

Comment: giving me the following error    Error in UseMethod("html_nodes") : 
  no applicable method for 'html_nodes' applied to an object of class "c('xml_document', 'xml_node')"

Comment: I keep forgetting I'm using the github versions of `rvest` and `xml2` (the new CRAN version of `rvest` [coming soon] will support this). If you can `devtools::install_github("hadley/rvest")` (and `xml2`) it'll work.